# Trying to Create a query that returns the oldest date for all records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `SQL Server` Database and I have two `tables`, `Certificates` and `Categories`.  There is a one to many relationship, each `Certificate` can have many `categories`.  I'm trying to create a query  that will show all of the certificates in the database, but only return one record with the oldest exp date for each category.  I've looked up a post that does almost exactly what I'm looking for

But there is a finite number of records it is searching through.  I've read around and found different ways to do this in other types of databases, but no efficient way to do this in ms sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one efficient way to solve such queries in most databases that I know of, called the `JOIN`. Together with PK-FK relations and indexes, this would be efficient enough for most of the purpose you'd ever come across. Try learning these and you'll discover what I'm talking about.

For this specific problem, you simply need to `JOIN` the two tables and  `GROUP` on the category field, using `MIN` aggregate function on exp date field. If you could supply the tables structure, we may be able to write the query too.

Comment: I decided to get back to basics like you suggested and it seems to have worked by using the correct groupby and MIN in the query designer, no coding required.  Thanks for putting be back at Step 1

Answer (score 2):

For this, you want to use the `row_number()` function:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category order by expdate desc) as seqnum
      from certificates c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1
```

This works on SQL Server versions 2005 and greater.

On older versions or in Access, you need to do a join to get this:

```
select c.*
from certifications c join
     (select category, max(expdate) as maxexpdate
      from certifications 
      group by category
     ) csum
     on c.category = csum.category and
        c.expddate = csum.maxexpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will fit the need.

```
SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Certificates Cert INNER JOIN
    (SELECT CerificateId,MIN(ExpiryDate)
    FROM dbo.Categories
    GROUP BY CerificateId) AS LatestCategories
    ON Cert.CerificateId = LatestCategories.CerificateId
```